# getting error in flask while running the app

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am building a rest API using flask and when I run I am getting `The method is not allowed for the requested URL.` I don't know where I am doing wrong

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    solute = request.form.get("solute")
    solvent = request.form.get("solvent")
    results = predictions(solute, solvent)

    response = {}
    response["response"] = {
        'energy': str(results)
    }
    return flask.jsonify(response)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3000, debug=True)
```

Here solute and solvent take data and results are in the form of a floating point in json format

Comment: first, make sure `<form .. >` tag has already `method="POST"` attribute

Comment: I am going to use this in a react app. so didn't have any HTML file here@cizario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you told us wich flask version are you using and which Python interpreter ? I copy paste your API adding predictions method and library for flask and it run perfectly without this error message.

Perhaps this error is trigger by another route ? Are u sure it come from this part ?

Here te entire code that i use to trigger this error but nothing happen.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.json import jsonify
 
app = Flask(__name__)

def predictions(solute, solvent):
    res = float(solute) + float(solvent)
    return res

@app.route('/predict', methods=["POST"])
def predict():

    solute = request.form.get('solute')
    solvent = request.form.get('solvent')
    result = predictions(solute, solvent)

    response = {}
    response["response"] = {
        'energy': str(result)
    }
    return jsonify(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=3000)
```

I'm using POSTMAN to send the POST request with data inside Body as form-data, please make sure you send correct query, perhaps the error come from here.

Return query with solute = 2.3 and solvent = 11.5

```
{
    "response": {
        "energy": "13.8"
    }
}
```